# Is $\oint_{\left | z \right |=2} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z(z^{2}+1))}dz$ equal to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I based my analysis on the fact that the only residue that's outside the curve is the reside in $\infty$ that's equal to zero, so all the other resides inside the curves must add to zero too.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yea. <enter hand wave mode> Basically when you reverse the curve, you're integrating around infinity, and you can apply the residue theorem there. Note: there's no singularity at infinity, so you shouldn't speak of a "residue at infinity", which, of course, is zero.

Comment: You are correct. The integral over a positively oriented curve enclosing all singularities in $\mathbb C$, $2 \pi i$ times the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion around infinity and $-2 \pi i$ times the residue at infinity are all the same thing (essentially because the Laurent series can be integrated termwise). Here the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ is zero because the function is $O(|z|^{-3})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $w=1/z$ gives
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{1/z}}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz=\int_{|w|=1/2}\frac{we^w}{1+w^2}\,dw=0$$
by Cauchy's theorem. This is basically the same as your argument that there
are no singularities outside the circle.

Comment: Well now I feel like a dingus.

Comment: Thanks that's what I tried to validate, you explained more elegantly than me. Thank you both for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Yes (the integral is zero), but not for the reason you think. I don't know of a relation between singularities inside and outside the contour of integration, so I'll do it the old-fashioned way.

Inside $|z|=2$ the integrand $f(z)$ has three singularities: two simple poles at $z=\pm i$ and an essential singularity at $z=0$. A straightforward calculation gives:
$$
\text{Res}(f;z=\pm i) = \frac{-1}{2}e^{\mp i}
$$ For the singularity at $z=0$, we should appeal to the series expansion:
$$
e^{w} =1+w+w^2/2+w^3/6+\cdots;\qquad e^{1/z} = 1 + z^{-1}+z^{-2}/2+z^{-3}/6+\cdots
$$
$$
\text{Res}(f;z=0) = \text{Res}\left(\frac{1 + z^{-1}+z^{-2}/2+z^{-3}/6+\cdots}{z(z^2+1)};z=0\right) 
$$
$$
\text{Res}\left(\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-j-1}}{j!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^k \right);z=0\right)
$$Multiplying this out using the Cauchy product gives the residue, i.e. the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, as
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^l}{(2l)!}=\cos(1)
$$Then the residue theorem gives
$$
\oint_{\left | z \right |=2} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z(z^{2}+1)}\,dz = 2\pi i\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{- i}-\frac{1}{2}e^{i}+\cos(1)\right)=0
$$

---

An incomplete attempt at an 'honest' solution:

Put $z=2 e^{i\theta},$ $dz=2i e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$\oint_{\left | z \right |=2} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z(z^{2}+1)}\,dz = i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ \exp\left(\frac{e^{-i \theta }}{2}\right)}{1+4 e^{2 i \theta }}\,d\theta$$ At this point (ignoring the $i$ out front), one could split the integrand into real and imaginary parts. The real part $R$ of the integrand satisfies $R(\theta)=-R(2\pi -\theta)$, so that integrates to zero. Mathematica claims the imaginary part integrates to zero as well but I can't quite show it.

Comment: ok, that's agood solution as my issue was with the essential singularity. But I also wanted to check if I could use this property $\sum_{n}^{}Res[f(z),z_{n})] = -Res[F(z),\infty] = 0$